# Religious/spiritual healing and prescriptions

Tags: discussion

Should this site be used for question of the following ilk:

1. > I/this person is having this issue. What dua/prayer should I be reciting to remedy it?
2. > How many times should I be reciting ... to get ... ?
3. > My husband is not speaking to me what should I recite, and how many time, to the make him get back to normal?
4. > I love ... but ... doesn't ... I have heard reading ... and recite ... this many times will make ... love me and marry me? Is that true? If not what is the correct ... ?
5. > My son doesn't listen to me and getting out of hand could somebody prescribe me some taweez or dua to recite and blow on him to get him on the right path and make him listen to me?
6. > My daughter-in-law is ... ?
7. > [... is irate any wazifa to fix it?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/10155/3487)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reckon that the site should not be used for these types of question, not due to any inherent off-topicness of dua/wazifa/tawiz-seeking itself (I admit I know little about this practice or its place in Islam), rather because **these questions typically do not come from any *academic* interest in the topic.**

Rather than showing any intent to *learn* about Islam — even if only to learn enough to solve the problem themselves — questions of this ilk can  basically be summed up as "I have a problem.  Fix it for me."  They are effectively **the Islamic equivalent of Stack Overflow's "Plz email me teh codez."**

Needless to say, "Plz email me teh codez" questions are not taken very well over there.

This is not to say that all such questions are inherently non-academic, just that the onus of proving an academic nature should be on the question itself.  Expert answers to ones *peers* is one thing, where we can be reasonably assured that the questioner and intended audience have the required expertise and/or ability to judge an answer according to its merits, but just "prescribing" a solution to someone who's likely to follow it blindly without the ability to recognize its validity runs **a significant risk of being actively *harmful*.**

For much the same reason a doctor needs to be very careful providing medical advice, or a lawyer providing legal advice, or even a priest providing pastoral advice — and one should be very careful seeking such from *random people on the internet* — we should not be seen as a source for such "prescriptions."  **Unless the question is phrased in such a way that it (and subsequent answers) would serve an *academic* interest in Islam, it should probably be closed.**

Comment: I wonder what's the origin of **"Plz email me teh codez"**. As in, was the phrase tossed to represent that category, or somebody did actually write it up.

Comment: @hus787 It takes various forms, but the meme is generally recognizable as a form of "I have spent little to no effort on this, I just want the answer."  http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19780/132874

Comment: Shouldn't this be added in the off-topic reasons?

Comment: @BleedingFingers We can only have three predefined options in the "off-topic reasons" list; adding this one would necessitate removing one of the others, which probably warrants a whole discussion in itself to decide which one should go.

Comment: [so] being the only exception I suppose.

Comment: @BleedingFingers Relevant Meta.SO discussion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185097/132874

Comment: I understand and agree with your reasoning. But can we still leave a comment suggesting solutions from our experience out of a brotherly sympathy (now that the question is already there and a comment would not make it any worse) without giving the impression of an official SE approval for example by reminding that "this question is off-topic but you can..." and if necessary warning that "such questions will be immediately deleted next time"?

Comment: @infatuated comments are not designed for answering questions.  if you want to talk about stuff like that, just take it to chat.

Answer (score 0):

This site is about Islam and Indeed Islam contains such parts and we can not cut some parts of Islam and make a version of Islam that we prefer.

I think there is no problem. but only if the answer is based on Quran verses or authentic hadith. and not from unreliable sources like deviated sufism rituals.

This site should not only for those who have academic interest. anyone interested in any part of Islam can know about those parts of Islam even if they are not academic parts of Islam. although saying "this part of Islam is not academic" is basically false because every part of Islam can be academic and if academics do not pay enough attention to those parts it is problem of academics.

Such spiritual parts of Islam are two parts: some are general and without any potential harm and some are specific to persons and applying them to others have no effect or perhaps harm. if the answers be limited to those who have reference in Quran and authentic hadith then we can ensure they are general and will have no harm.