# Should it be allowed to ask for religious text which are there in the books but not available over the internet?

Tags: discussion

Should it be allowed to ask for religious text e.g. *[Text of the condolence which is given to Muhammad(saww) on the Day of Ashura?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/10781/3487)*, which is available in religious books but not available over the internet, along with the translation and possibly the transliteration as well?

Comment: Why not allow this?

Comment: Just a discussion. Plus I didn't want this to be characterized as [Religious/spiritual healing and prescriptions](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/853/3487).

Comment: Plus the community should have say and it's better to bring it up rather than assume.

Comment: are you sure reputable duas are not available on internet? http://duas.org/ if you mean books like deviated sufism, then that is a different matter. but authentic duas have no problem.

Comment: Sometimes it's better to bring it up *and* assume, i.e. post your question on the main site normally, then bring up the discussion on meta pointing to and/or defending your post.  Seeing a concrete example, and how the community reacts to it, can be valuable for discussion.

Comment: @goldPseudo Point noted and concurred.

Answer (score 3):

In general, I don't see a problem with this. It mostly sounds like a case of [source-identification](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-identification), which is to say you are searching for a *particular and specific* reference, rather than a vague "[Are there any dua for...](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/853/22)" (which would effectively just be a list question).

In other words, it's objectively answerable.  You're not seeking [items, or ideas, or opinions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/), you're seeking an *answer*, and you know (or reasonably suspect) that there is an existing text out there which *does* answer your question.

As long as the question itself is good (i.e. not just an excuse to [copy-paste](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/324/22) text verbatim from a third-party), the requested source being online or offline shouldn't make a difference (although, under the principle of [Making the Internet a Better Place](http://stackexchange.com/), I'd love to see more offline-specific requests since that information is otherwise so difficult to find online).

Whether the question and requested source is any good (which is to say *useful*) would have to be left up to community voting; even if we wanted to, I doubt we could really set any hard and fast rules on what is, and is not, useful to the community.  Like any question, the onus is still on the questioner to prove its value.