# Can we make sure to not throw away logic and reason?

Tags: discussion

I am a lurker (active on majority of the Science SE network as I am a graduate Applied Math student). I usually read the questions/answers here to help me understand Islam and bring me closer to it.

That being said, it is in my opinion, the following question/answers should not be allowed on this website: [Click here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/18581/how-to-deal-with-blackmagic)

The question in hand talks about a relative/family member delivering black magic to other family members. An "observation" by the poster said his father's bone broke unexpectedly. He also observed a few other "black magic" occurrences. He provided no basis/evidence.   Must be throw away all rational and logic when it comes to these questions? A broken bone has many real-world explanations. It may also indicate a deeper medical condition, and the father should seek immediate medical help.

Not to mention, it breaks the laws of physical reality. The question is not about whether **black magic exists or not** but about a physical possession. Ignoring the laws of physics is not justified. We should pay extra attention to not automatically attribute the currently unexplained phenomena to spiritual castings/black magic.

I've noticed that the site emphasizes on proofs. A proof for something needs a valid hypothesis, a valid question in our context. I don't think the question is valid. Not to mention that the father may have a serious vitamin/calcium deficiency and not a single answer mentioned to go to a doctor.

Comment: Not getting into the discussion of what black-magic is actually capable of doing, since it's a religious matter and many of the things in religion science considers as impossible. Period. That said, I think that question comes under the umbrella of [Religious/spiritual healing and prescriptions](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/853) which is currently off-topic. Haven't voted to close it since am not entirely certain that it belongs to that category. You could add more focus on that topic by [edit]ing the discussion or a new discussion about it could be started.

Comment: Do you mean to say that black magic should _never_ be discussed in the context of this site, or that this question is a bad one because there is no reason to believe that the occurrence wasn't natural?

Comment: Oh, I didn't. Discussing black magic is different than automatically using black magic to explain the unexplained. The answers in the thread never even considered the logic and rationality of what the OP said. The OP and the answers should've done more research to help explain the unexplained phenomenon happening to the father.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question asked is very valid because according to Islam (not to mention esoteric sciences) black magic exists and can negatively affect people in so many ways. Black magic can indeed transfer some of the control of your body into the hands of demons. The person affected can then demonstrate strange uncontrolled behaviors and experiences. The well-known evil eye is also closely related to this subject which again is confirmed by Islam.

As for the assumption that these incidents contradict "physics" it must be noted that modern natural sciences suffer from fundamental defects in their basic assumptions and therefore they can and should not be taken as a criteria to determine what is real or mythical. (For an extensive and profound discussion of this I recommend [*The Reign of Quantity and the Signs of the Times*](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Reign-Quantity-Signs-Collected-Guenon/dp/0900588675) by the Gnostic philosopher Rene Guenon.) For this particular question, the Cartesian separation of matter from spirit comes to my mind implying that matter can only be influenced by other material agents, which is also rejected by Neoplatonic/gnostic (including muslim) philosophers.

There is also this assumption that "laws of physics" as we know them are inviolable, whereas according to Gnostic philosophy all natural phenomena as we see them are not only being constantly governed and shaped by supernatural agents (angels or demons) in the first place — this is even logically demonstrated by Muslims philosophers — but the same supernatural agents can be invoked to influence nature to work in ways different from the normal circumstances. For example objects under normal circumstances are pulled by the gravity but a spiritually empowered soul can produce a counter force overcoming that of gravity and thus enabling the person or objects to raise from the ground. However not all these spiritual capabilities are considered legitimate according to Islam. Prophets are examples of those who enjoy legitimate forms of such supernatural powers.

Comment: But unless you're certain that it actually *is* black magic you can't forgo pay doctor a visit. Which OP's (trying to) allude to. Allow such questions could be dangerous to personal health of users and visitors alike since they would try to associate all illness to black magic and then you know.

Comment: @BleedingFingers, yes, you're right. However questions on this topic can be general not addressing specific cases. Such as the Islamic view of black magic.

Comment: You can't equate observable science to philosophical thinking. Half the questions/arguments in philosophy don't have solid base to stand on. I also ask you why you think modern natural sciences suffer from fundamental defects in their basic assumptions. I am not arguing whether supernatural powers exist. I am saying that modern science forbids all matter to break the laws of physics.

Comment: @masfenix
This is a very extensive topic, involving many profound questions of epistemology that can't be discussed without basic knowledge of philosophy fundamentals and much less in comments gere. That's why I recommended you a book. But we may discuss some basics of the question in chat or you may want to work it out into a specific question and post it on philosophy.se and I might consider answering it.

Comment: @infatuated It doesn't matter. I am not talking about philosophy here. No amount of philosophical thought can change the observable universe. If you choose to have certain beliefs that contradict evidence, then so be it. But back to the point. These questions are dangerous as they are impossible to occur in our natural world.

Comment: @masfenix, it does matter! Because you keep repeating the dogmas of modern 'science'!

Comment: No it doesn't because we are not talking about a philosophy. We are talking about a physical manifestation of magic and breaking the laws of physics. The discussion is valid if you are going to talk about it "philosophically" which has no right/wrong answer. Basically the problem is abstract vs concrete. The OP's question wasn't in an abstract sense. It was concrete, and a ordinary human can not break the laws of physics. It's really that simple. Any unexplained phenomena HAS an explanation, just hidden to us in our time. We should NEVER attribute it to magic.

Comment: I don't think the OP is saying that questions of black magic should be off topic in general on I.SE (I'll post a comment on the OP to find out). I think the point is that there is really no reason to think that the situation described in the linked question _is_ black magic as opposed to some natural phenomenon.

Comment: "according to Islam (not to mention esoteric sciences) black magic exists" ... Where does it say this in the Qur'an please?

Comment: @aasheq, The story of Pharaoh's magicians' encounter with Moses is one of famous Quranic themes in its ancient accounts!

Comment: Yes, but it does not say that their magic worked. The implication is that they were fake magicians.

Comment: @aasheq, It DID work in the eyes of the viewers (they were really affected by their magic) until the magicians' work was neutralized by miracles performed by Moses.

Comment: Some people are impressed by side-show magicians. This does not prove that their "magic" is real.

Comment: @aasheq, That's conjuring not magic. Magic is about manipulating and influencing things using supernatural agents (jins for example).

Comment: Quranic reference to magic as a real influential factor: http://tanzil.net/#2:102

Answer (score 1):

We already discourage such questions, not because black magic is illogical and/or violates the laws of physics, but because as a site we are just plain not suited to determining whether an issue actually *is* magical/spiritual in nature rather than mundane, nor do we have — nor can we be *expected* to have — sufficient information/training/authority to actually *prescribe* appropriate healing to such a problem.

Just like taking medical advice from random strangers on the Internet (rather than a licensed doctor) is invariably a terrible idea, so too seeking spiritual healing is inevitably better asked of people who (a) know what they're doing and (b) are known to know what they're doing (in other words, established professionals).  See the relevant meta discussion here: [Religious/spiritual healing and prescriptions](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/853/22)